# ASP.NET Website Losing Session Variables When Loging In With IE

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, iis, authentication

I am trying to fix an ASP.NET application that is also written is VB and uses session variables to store the information from the logging page. In Firefox, the application runs just fine, but in IE (I am using IE 8), when I summit the logging credentials, the session variables become empty (takes me back to the logging page).

The weird thing is that when I move the privacy settings in IE (doesn't matter if high to low, or low to high) and enter the logging information again, the application runs great. Also if I restart IIS 6.0 the application runs great. What's going on? Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the application is written using Visual Studio 2003 with .NET 1.1

Comment: I used the IIS 5.0 isolation mode and the application runs fine. The only problem is that IE ask me for my credentials on one of the pages, and it doesn't authenticate me. On the other hand Firefox does.

Comment: I have been testing the application in IIS 5.0 isolation mode and the only problem is that pages that requires accessing some resources in the directories don't work because of permission problem; it says something like "access to the path SOMEDIRECTORY was denied". On the other hand, the logging-session problem disappeared. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Session object uses a browser cookie to identify the session from one page to the next.  Do you have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes I have cookies enabled in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Once you restart IIS, how long does it work fine for?

You might be encountering some Application Pool issues.

Is this a new site?  If so, you might have some architecture issues.

Comment: The site is new and is not on production yet. I have tested it for about an hour, and there are times (randomly) when it requires re-entering the credentials.

Comment: If after an hour suddenly you need to re-enter your credentials, what is your session timeout?  Is it on a sliding expiration or absolute expiration?

Comment: I used the IIS 5.0 isolation mode and the application runs fine. The only problem is that IE ask me for my credentials on one of the pages, and it doesn't authenticate me. On the other hand Firefox does.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to same problem, I fixed by using this code:
`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="160" cookieless="UseUri"></sessionState>`
I actually tried to use this and it didn't work until I change the `cookiless` to `"UseUri"`.
It took me 2 days to solve so I want to share even though your question is old as 2 years.

Answer (score -1):

What's the setting of the smartnavigation property? try setting it to false, I have had strange behaviour similar to yours in the past.

Comment: Is that property in every page? sorry, I am new to ASP.